# SVM Classifying binary data DNA

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, svm, libsvm

I'm working SVM in R software and I would appreaciate any input you may provide.
I have a data set that I need to train with SVM, the format of the data is the following

```
ToPredict   Data1      Data2        Data3    Data4         DNA
S            1          12             1       11          000000000100
B           -1          17            14        3          11011110111110111
S            1          4              0        4          0000
```

The question that I have is regarding the DNA column.

SVM is able to get an input like DNA and still calculate reliable predictions? 
For my data set, 0≠00 or 1≠001 therefore, it cannot be taken as integers.Every value represents information that needs to be processed and the order is very important, it's a string of binary values, either is 1 or 0.

The 0101 information could be displayed as ABAB etc. (A=0, B=1)

How can I train a SVM with the data above?

Thank you.

Comment: hi! i think it's possible but you might be in a better position to answer that by trying a few different things! you could set the length of the longest DNA string you have as the standard, and for each row, fill in the column in that row with one of three possible values: - 1, 0 and -1 or something else for unknown. you could also try to use the length of the original DNA string as a feature. if all your columns/features are going to have very different ranges, you might want to consider normalizing i.e. distribute your values over a small range of [-1,1] or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For SVMs to work, "all" you need to have a kernel function.

So what is a sensible kernel function for your "DNA strings"? You probably don't need to be able to prove it is a proper kernel, but you can get away with a good similarity measure.

How would you evaluate similarity of your sequences? I cannot help you on that, because I don't know what the data means; this is up to the user (i.e. you) to specify.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Currently, I'm using the RBF kernel, and the way I select it is to perform a 10-cross fold validation and choosing the less error percentage. The data is oriented to financial markets, I simply set: Bar up=1, Bar down=0, then I start the sequence for the trend. Data1 specifies the kind of trend, 1=Trend Up, -1=Trend Down. Data2=Amount of bars, Data3=amount of bars Up, Data4=Amount of bars down.